# Using a join statement in Doctrine when no parameters are required

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I am trying to add a join statement to my DQL in my search functionality, as one of the fields that a user can search is actually linked with another table, notably a customer name which is only referenced in the root table as an id.

I have seen how the join syntax should work on the Doctrine site (example only below):

```
$qb->join('u.Group', 'g', 'WITH', 'u.status = ?1', 'g.id')
```

but I don't want to match a specific value, I only want to join it the way I would in mySQL as follows:

```
...JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.existingCustomer
```

Here is my current search DQL, where `m` represents a table called Message and `c` represents a table called Customer:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');
$qb->select('m');
$qb->where('c.firstName LIKE :s');
$qb->orWhere('c.surname LIKE :s');
$qb->orWhere('m.postcode LIKE :s');
$qb->orWhere('m.town LIKE :s');
$qb->orWhere('m.phone1 LIKE :s');
$qb->andWhere('m.archived = :archived');
$qb->orderBy('m.messageDate', 'DESC')
    ->setParameter('s', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->setParameter('archived', 0);
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

As you can see there is reference to `c` which is meant to be the alias for the Customer table, as the Message table ONLY uses an id to cross reference this.

What I need to know is, is there a way to join the Customer table by linking the `existingCustomer` field in the Message table to the `id` field of the Customer table without having to match a specific value in order to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
us \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join;
// ...
->leftJoin('YourBundle:Table2', 'table2', Join::WITH, 'table2.id = table1.existingCustomer')
```